# Implementing multiple mat-icon in angular 6 project the same svg icon appears in multiple places

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material

I am adding the svg-icons dynamically in the app.component.ts file using the code 
format of the icon's json array to loop over is

> [{'icon-name': 'ICON1' 'icon-url','assets/imgs/icon1.svg'}, {'icon-name': 'ICON2' 'icon-url','assets/imgs/icon2.svg'} ]

The MatIconRegistery is injected in the constructor:

```
 constructor(private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

this.listOfIcons.forEach(icon => {
                this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(icon.icon-name,
                this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(icon-url.url));
            });
```

In the html we have the following tag:

The dumb component is as below:

However, the same icon is displaying in multiple locations in the angular project. I would like to know how to view svg files in an Angular 6 project ?

Answer (score 1):

### There is a chance the issue is actually with the SVG files.

If your SVG files have the same class or id attribute names, it could run into some conflicts with each other when they render.

For other people with this issue, they had duplicate id attribute names that needed to be changed.

For me, I had duplicate id AND class attribute names. However, **I only needed to change the class names**.

It seems everyone's situation is a little different however the common factor is duplicate names between different SVG files with the same class or id attribute names.

---

My first SVG that I left unchanged with the class name "cls-1":

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 134">
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;fill-rule:evenodd;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>Glitch_White_RGB</title>
    <path class="cls-1" d="M89,77l-9,23v94h32v17h18l17-17h26l35-35V77H89Zm107,76-20,20H144l-17,17V173H100V89h96v64Zm-20-41v35H164V112h12Zm-32,0v35H132V112h12Z" transform="translate(-80 -77)" />
</svg>
```

My second SVG where I changed the class name to "cls-2":

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 134">
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-2{fill:#6441a4;fill-rule:evenodd;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>Glitch</title>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M89,77l-9,23v94h32v17h18l17-17h26l35-35V77H89Zm107,76-20,20H144l-17,17V173H100V89h96v64Zm-20-41v35H164V112h12Zm-32,0v35H132V112h12Z" transform="translate(-80 -77)" />
</svg>
```

I originally posted my solution [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15631#issuecomment-508285866).
The original comment that helped me resolve my issue is [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14959#issuecomment-481797135).